# Using ASP.Net Impersonation w/ Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, iis-6, impersonation

We have a web application that copies files to a remote server within our domain (**OurDomain**). The following issue occurs with users that log on to their laptop with another domain, and then log on to the web application with **OurDomain**. Users that log on to both the laptop and web application with **OurDomain\User** don't have this problem.

We have two webforms:

The 1st webform retrieves the user's ID using `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` and then sends an email with this userid. This code retrieves the user's ID only if we have `Windows Authentication` set to `Enabled` and `ASP.Net Impersonation` also set to `Enabled`. If `ASP.Net Impersonation` is set to `Disabled`, the user will be `Network Service`. So I set both to Enabled and everything here works great.

The 2nd webform copies some files to the remote server, also under the domain **OurDomain**. With `Windows Authentication` set to `Enabled` and `ASP.Net Impersonation` set to `Disabled`, then `Network Service` is used to copy the files to the remote server and are copied correctly. On the other hand, If `ASP.Net Impersonation` is set to `Enabled`, it seems to bypass `Network Service` and even **OurDomain\User** and tries to copy with, apparently, the credentials used to log on to the laptop (Another domain). The files don't copy and I get error *Access to the path is denied*

The only fix I've found is to add **OurDomain\User** to the folder, and it's really not a big deal, but I wanted to see why this was happening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe OurDomain\User is the user who is logged into the system from web browser. It is not a good security practice to give server folder access to that group of users. If you give access to those users they can even browse the remote folder without your web application.

NetworkService is a user who has role on in the system where it is created.

Better create a user as asp.net appPool user in OruDomain\webappuser ie the user who runs the w3wp worker process. Let the password with be the admin.Give OurDomain\webappuser the permission on the remote folder. Run the web form without impersonation.

Now the files which are received via file upload dialog in webform2 can be copied to the folder safely as the asp.net application run in the context of OurDomain\webappuser

Comment: I cannot create/modify or in any way alter users in OurDomain.

Comment: If there is no way to have a app pool user other than the network service you may need to impersonation. ie the asp.net application will execute as if the user logged in the browser execute a program in the web server. In that case if the user who logged in the browser has permission on the remote folder the file copy will work.